# Cannot install and use Nvidia drivers (Wheezy)

Tags: nvidia, debian

I have a build with the GTX 560 TI card every time I try to install the Linux drivers (with Debian Wheezy and using [tecmint.com](http://www.tecmint.com/install-nvidia-drivers-in-linux/) or [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers) as a guide), I always end up restarting X or the computer (same thing really) and X never starts correctly.

The closest I got was using the [first guide](http://www.tecmint.com/install-nvidia-drivers-in-linux/) there and I actually got it to say that it couldn't find the device "nvidia" and there were no screens. I'm really not sure what to do from here.

(if there is a log I can provide you with please let me know)

Comment: Do you have an `xorg.conf` file? If you don't, this is not going to work. If you do, then paste it into your question, please.

Comment: Please do not proceed that way, and do not make a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian). Debian provides, thanks to the `non-free` repository, the Nvidia proprietary `nvidia-driver` package.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use the script provided by the Nvidia website, [you are likely to break your system (and making a FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian), like you seemed to have.

The viable and stable method is to use the one in the Debian wiki, which is, in short, the following:

#### 1) Know your Debian distribution codename:

```
 $ lsb_release -a | grep Codename
```

#### 2) Add the `contrib` and `non-free` repositories

You need to modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by adding "contrib" and "non-free" after "main". For example, if your are using "buster":

> deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free

#### 3) Update your package manager cache:

```
 # apt update
```

#### 4) Install your kernel headers and the Nvidia proprietary driver:

```
 # apt install apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//') nvidia-driver
```

#### 5) Reboot the system

```
 # reboot
```

You should be all set, with all the necessary tools to get your GPU stats and settings, with `nvidia-smi` and `nvidia-settings` for example. Please note that you do not need to have a `xorg.conf` since wheezy except for some fine-tuning.

Answer (score -1):

The way I installed proprietary drivers last time (on plain Debian):

1. I installed a Debian system from scratch (from the offical netinstall iso)
2. Downloaded the driver to the "Downloads" directory (where things always go when you click "download").
3. Pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (in order to switch to one of the full-screen terminals.)
4. From the full screen console ran:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/gdm3 stop
   ```

(To kill the graphic interface. Otherwise the installer won't run)

4. Then I navigated to the Downloads directory - where the Nvidia driver is ("cd Downloads")
5. Before running the downloaded installer I had to do:

   ```
   apt-get install build-essential

   apt-get install linux-headers*
   ```

(Otherwise the installer will complain about these missing and exit)

6. Then I ran the downloaded file

   ```
   sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.32.run
   ```

The installer complained about nouveau not being disabled, but turned it off for me without problems. Then asked to restart the computer and to run it again after reboot.

```
reboot
```

then

```
cd Downloads
sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.32.run
```

The installer then went through ok and I had to just reboot one final time. That's it.

Comment: Please do not proceed that way, and do not make a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian). Debian provides, thanks to the `non-free` repository, the Nvidia proprietary `nvidia-driver` package.